# ggplot() data sorting with dates in X and Y axis - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, data-science

I am developing a Taipan Chart that would show date variations to different items.
I got completely stuck to sort out the data by the Reporting date order to have the line ( `geom_path()` ) connecting the points in that order.

I was trying to sort it as you can see in the code. However, nothing is happening.

Could you please help me with this issue? Data Link .csv : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MUJn4zPNIkZu1bEq_qNdConVLsDeebzv/view

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

x <- as.Date(dataset$"Due Date", "%Y-%m-%d")
y <- as.Date(dataset$"Reporting Date", "%Y-%m-%d")
Item <- dataset$"Key Work Activity / Milestone"


ggplot(dataset[order(dataset$"Reporting Date"),], aes (x,y,colour = factor(Item))) + 
 geom_path(size = 1) + 
 labs( x = "Forecast Date", y = "Reporting Date") + 
 theme(
   legend.position = "bottom",
   panel.background = element_rect(fill=NA, colour = NA),
   panel.grid.major = element_line (size = 0.1, linetype = "solid", colour = "black")
 )+
 geom_point(size=3) + 
 geom_hline(yintercept = Sys.Date(), linetype = "dashed" , colour ="blue") + 
 geom_vline(xintercept = Sys.Date(), linetype = "dashed", colour = "blue") +
 scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y", date_breaks = "1 month") + 
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) + 
 scale_y_date(date_labels = "%b %Y", date_breaks = "1 month") +
 theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 45))
```

This is what I am trying to achieve [image]

This is what I have now [image]

Comment: Why do you sort with the `Index` column and not the `Reporting date` column? Since you do not provide any data, it is difficult to understand what `Index` stands for and provide you a solution.

Comment: @Hobo Sheep I have removed the Index column where I tried manually sort the Reporting Date. Therefore, I removed the Order <- dataset$"Index" line and edited dataset[order(dataset$"Index"),] to dataset[order(dataset$"Reporting Date"),]. However, the result stays the same. It looks like it does not sort the data or build the connections only according to the X- axis sequence and not the Y- axis. Thank you.

Comment: Hum... Could you provide a small sample of the dataset so that we can test solutions?

Comment: @Hobo Sheep Please follow the link to download the .csv data sample. 
 Thank you. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MUJn4zPNIkZu1bEq_qNdConVLsDeebzv/view)

Comment: Is this the exact dataset you've been using to produce the plots in your question? From what I see, the plotting works with a proper data formatting (`format = "%d/%m/%Y"`), but your grouping variable seems to be not refined enough, leading to a lot of horizontal links (between rows sharing the same `Reporting Date` since they are ordered by this variable.